# Does Vulkan support local subgroup memory sharing and manipulation?

Tags: memory, gpu, vulkan, gpu-local-memory

In OpenCL I could use `__local` whenever I wanted to manipulate subgroup memory. Analogically CUDA has `__shared__` keyword.
Does Vulkan have something equivalent? I cannot see anything in the subgroup tutorial
https://www.khronos.org/blog/vulkan-subgroup-tutorial although I do see that they mention *shared memory*, but they never actually explain how to initialize it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vulkan compute shader for parallel sum reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68586498/vulkan-compute-shader-for-parallel-sum-reduction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vulkan supports `shared` buffers. They are better described here

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_Shader#Shared_variables

An example of usage might look as follows

```
layout (local_size_x = 32) in;

layout(std430, set = 0, binding = 1) buffer SomeBuffer{
    int some_ints[];
};

shared int[32] shared_ints;

void main(){
   shared_ints[gl_LocalInvocationID.x] = some_ints[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x];
}
```

Comment: The word is workgroup then? Workgroup - block of threads that gets dispatched, can share data through shared memory, synchronise with barriers; And subgroups are waves(AMD) or warps(nvidia), part of a workgroups, where all threads execute same instruction at a time. If you want to move data within subgroup with extension you use shuffle or broadcast.

Comment: This terminology is so confusing. Do you perhaps know of some place that describes it in detail?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_threads